# Setting path for QgsLayoutItemPicture using PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, layouts, png, path

In PyQGIS I want to define a path for a `QgsLayoutItemPicture`.

Example:

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.setName("test")

picture_path = "Sursee.jpg"
picture = QgsLayoutItemPicture(layout)
picture.setPicturePath(picture_path)

layout.addLayoutItem(picture)
manager.addLayout(layout)
```

If I set the picture path with setPicturePath, the picture is still in SVG-mode, not in raster mode (see below).

[image]

How can the mode of the `QgsLayoutItemPicture` can be adjusted?

Source: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Layout/QgsLayoutItemPicture.html#qgis.core.QgsLayoutItemPicture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`QgsLayoutItemPicture.setMode()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.30/core/QgsLayoutItemPicture.html#qgis.core.QgsLayoutItemPicture.setMode) (see [here](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.30/core/QgsLayoutItemPicture.html#qgis.core.QgsLayoutItemPicture.Format) for available formats):

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.setName("test")
picture_path = "tile.png"
picture = QgsLayoutItemPicture(layout)
picture.setPicturePath(picture_path)
layout.addLayoutItem(picture)

# set the picture format to raster
picture.setMode(1)
# or 
# picture.setMode(QgsLayoutItemPicture.FormatRaster)

manager.addLayout(layout)
```

[image]

Comment: So next time I have to check the latest QGIS Docs. In the 3,20 Doc there was no setMode(). Thank you for your fast response! @Matt

Comment: Glad to help. One thing of note is that it doesn't seem to work when the mode is set *before* adding `picture` to the layout.

Comment: yeah, I saw this. I was confused first, but figured it out myself. Thanks!